# How to recursively remove all but list of files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rm

How can I recursively remove everything in a directory EXCEPT a small list of files to preserve?  For example, let's try to remove all files except ones named `f2` and `f5`.

```
# Create a testing ground
mkdir -p d{1..3}
touch d{1..3}/f{1..5}

# Remove all files EXCEPT ones named f2 and f5.
find . -type f -not -name ('f2'|'f5') -type f -exec rm -f '{}' +

# Remove empty directories
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Produces:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The end goal is to execute this from within a larger C userspace app, but using `system()` to execute a command line command seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -not \( -name f2 -o -name f5 \) -delete
```

should do it.

`-delete` is just like `-exec rm -f '{}' +` but shorter and even more efficient. Run it first without it though, to confirm it gets only the files you really do want deleted.

Comment: works great in the bash shell!  but not from within a `system()` call.  `system("find ./dummy_dir -type f -not \( -name 'f2' -o -name 'f5' \) -delete");`  still get the same syntax error on the leading open paren `(`.

Comment: If we're talking C here, then `\(` needs to be `\\(` or `'('`. Same for the closing parenthesis.

Comment: `\\` is a special character in C strings.